# Question from C++ Templates: The Complete guide 2nd

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
#include <cstring>
// maximum of two values of any type (call-by-reference)
template<typename T>
T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
    return b < a ? a : b;
}
// maximum of two C-strings (call-by-value)
char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)
{
    return std::strcmp(b,a) < 0 ? a : b;
}
// maximum of three values of any type (call-by-reference)
template<typename T>
T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    return max (max(a,b), c); // error if max(a,b) uses call-by-value
}
int main ()
{
    auto m1 = ::max(7, 42, 68); // OK
    char const* s1 = "frederic";
    char const* s2 = "anica";
    char const* s3 = "lucas";
    auto m2 = ::max(s1, s2, s3); // run-time ERROR
}
```

The problem is that if you call `max()` for three C-strings, the statement `return max (max(a,b), c);`
becomes a run-time error because for C-strings, `max(a,b)` creates a new, temporary local value that
is returned by reference, but that temporary value expires as soon as the return statement is complete, leaving `main()` with a dangling reference.

`max(a, b)` call nontemplate `::max(char const* a, char const* b)`, why it will create a new, temporary local value.

I tested this code on VS2022, no errors.

Comment: UB can lead to "seems to work".

Comment: *why it will create a new, temporary local value.*  Because the code is programmed to return a new temporary local value.  Change the code to return a reference to a parameter that was passed by reference — then the lifespan of the result depends upon the lifespan of the caller's arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function

```
T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    return max (max(a,b), c); // error if max(a,b) uses call-by-value
}
```

returns a reference to a temporary pointer of the type `const char *` returned  by the expression

```
max (max(a,b), c)
```

used in the return statement of the function because this function

```
char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)
{
    return std::strcmp(b,a) < 0 ? a : b;
}
```

returns a copy of the value of one of the pointers passed to it by value.

So the reference will be invalid because the temporary object will not be alive after exiting the function.

Comment: But why it works fine when running in VS2022?

Comment: @Haswell Because the memory allocated for the pointer was not overwritten. But you shall not rely on that. Undefined behavior can produce the expected result.